# Update to Sierra 10.12.1, C compilers, Xcode, and grace not working

Tags: xcode, macos, xmgrace

I updated my computer a couple days ago to Sierra 10.12.1, and now xmgrace is no longer working. I've been searching forums for ideas on how to fix this, but have had no success so far with what I've tried.

When I type

```
xmgrace
```

into the command line I get an error:

```
Warning: Widget must be a VendorShell.
Warning: Fatal Error: 
_XmGetDefaultDisplay cannot be used prior to VendorS.Initialize, returns NULL

Oops! Got SIGSYS

Please use "Help/Comments" to report the bug.
Abort trap: 6
```

While trying out pieces of advice I've found during a google search. I also found some other problems, but I'm not sure if they are a big deal. When I try to run a simple "hello world" program using gcc or g++ I get some warnings:

```
couldn't understand kern.osversion `16.1.0'
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$___extendhfsf2 in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$___truncdfhf2 in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$___truncsfhf2 in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$_atomic_flag_clear in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$_atomic_flag_clear_explicit in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$_atomic_flag_test_and_set in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$_atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$_atomic_signal_fence in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.10$_atomic_thread_fence in dylib /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.12$_dispatch_assert_queue in dylib /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.12$_dispatch_assert_queue_not in dylib /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os10.12$_dispatch_queue_create_with_target in dylib /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_basename_r in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_clock_getres in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_clock_gettime in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_clock_settime in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_dirname_r in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_getentropy in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_mkostemp in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$weak$os10.11$_mkostemps in dylib /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
```

However, the program does compile and the executable it produces works. When I try to run

```
xcode-select --install
```

I get a window that pops up asking permission to install. Once I click accept the search takes a while before throwing the error

```
Can't download the software because of a network problem
```

Edit: I downloaded Xcode directly from the Apple Developer website. Now, when I run this command, I get a error that Xcode is already installed.

When I run

```
xmgrace
```

in a terminal window I get the error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXt.7.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openmotif/lib/libXm.4.dylib
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm not really sure what to do. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working finally, with the help of a saint of a man at a computer repair shop near me. I think the biggest problem, which I didn't not recognize on my own was that macOS El Capitan 10.11.1 and Sierra 10.12.1 put restrictions on root. I rebooted my computer in recovery mode (command+R), then from utilities -> terminal I typed

```
csrutil disable
```

then restarting the computer normally, I made sure that Xcode was installed properly using a download from the apple developer website. I installed macports from a .pkg and then used

```
sudo port install openmotif
sudo port install grace
```

PS. I had some trouble with my first port install, which was solved by

```
sudo port install xorg-libXt +flat_namespace +universal
```